# In cron jobs (Python), what does the -m flag stand for and how is it used?

Tags: python, module, cron

I am trying to set up a cron job which is executing a python file of mine. The python file is using some manually installed modules. The cron job now throws an error, as it 'cannot find' the specified module (yes, I tested it: if executed manually the script does work & have access to the module).

I did now recieve the cryptic info (from the hoster’s support) to '*try adding the -m flag to the command, followed by the path to the module that it cannot find.*' Unfortunatelly I do not quite understand this advice.

Assuming that my cron job command (**via Cpanel**) would out of the box be:

```
0 * * * * python /home/public_html/cgi-bin/cronrun.py
```

which works if the python script does not rely on external modules.

So my questions are:

- Is the -m flag appropriate?
- If so, how do I use it?
- And what do I do, if there is more than just one additional module that the script needs?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You said you have access to the installed modules? Is the cron job set up under your user?

Comment: I’m a bit ashamed to say: I don’t know.
I did set the cron job up via the provided Cpanel. But I have no clue how/where it is set up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cron job won't likely be running with the same environment that you have. To see this, first run env > [somepath_that_you_can_reach]. Then set up a cron to do the same thing in a shell script using a different path. Compare the two. You will need your PYTHONPATH to be the same for the cron job to work. If that is the problem, then in your python script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('[the path part that you need for it to work]')
```

before your import statements.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I did check the "env" via ssh and via cron job - and they differ significantly!
Do you know if it is possible to also append paths to the "cron job environment"?
Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for this help!
I was now able to add the respective paths and the cron job is working fine :)
I would like to vote up your answer, but my rank is too low to do so. Thus, I can only say: THANK YOU!